# OAuth2 redirect URI required to be fully defined

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, uri

I must be missing something obvious.  I am developing a web app that will be shipped to a number of customers.  The app will be installed on a web server of their choice.  My problem is with the OAuth2 authentication and GA requiring me to register a redirect URI.  I can't know the URI ahead of time because it will contain whatever URL address they are using.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this?  Can I specify just a portion of the URI and have it be relative?

Thanks, I know the answer must be something simple.

Answer (score 1):

For your web app will be deployed in different customers' servers, they are different web app. So they should have their own Client ID, Client secret and Redirect URIs. You can make all this OAuth related params configurable, and let customers configure them or help them deploy it.

Comment: I have to believe there is an easier way other than making every deployment have its own client ID, secret, and fixed redirect.  Even in this scenario, if a customer moves the application they would have to recreate the keys which seems crazy.

Comment: If customer move their application, they need to add or change their redirect url, and I don't think this is frequent, for customer's domain is generally fixed.

Comment: I guess my thinking comes from previous applications.  We have built a similar app for Facebook and Twitter.  Both allow us to build the redirect URI at runtime (in the code) so we never need to know where the app is installed.  It means they are free to deploy it as they wish with no need to change anything.  It also means we can move it around during development without any changes.  This GA requirement to hardcode and register the redirect URI just seems to be too restrictive for normal application development.

Comment: Yes, for normal development this is a restriction, support run-time defined redirect_url is reasonable in your case, but support it or not depends on OAuth service provider.